# Showing decimals, binaries and hexadecimals with Java Script

Tags: javascript, binary, hex, decimal

First of all this is not a school assignement, i'm just on break trying to learn some Java Script ahead to be ready for the semestre.
I need to write a JS programm that shows a bunch of integers(let's say from 0 to 1000) and show their binary and hexadecimal representation next to them, i'm finding trouble to understand the process of doing this.
I will be very grateful to receive some help!
Thanks.

Comment: You know the for-loop, right? Loop from i = 0 to 1000 and during each iteration, you do `console.log(i, i.toString(2), i.toString(16))`. Now, if you want to display those results somewhere in your HTML document, post some code and layout and we can help you along if you can't solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,70]

for (var x = 0; x < nums.length; x++ ) {
    console.log('original: ', nums[x].toString(),'\tbinary: ',(nums[x] >>> 0).toString(2),'\thex: ',nums[x].toString(16))
}
```

don't be afraid to google specifically what you need. you're bound to come across tons of examples ;)